# DevExpress ASPXScheduler

Tags: .net, asp.net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress AspxScherduler control.

How can i disable selection of multiple rows. For example: Minimum appointment duration is 5 minutes, and i need to enable client to select only 5 minute for appointment, i want to disable multiple selection of times, and only selection of appointment of 5 minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tried to find a solution to your task but to no avail.  This functionality is not supported by the ASPxScheduler and there is no way to achieve it :(.